# Background task expired while holding WebKit ProcessAssertion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webkit

I have this radio app streaming that it was working until apple decide to upgrade to IOS 13, now it will work while the screen is on but if you switch apps or let the screen unattended and dims until it turn off it will work for about 20 sec and kill the music, if you go directly to the player using safari it works perfect. I am using html because I found it how to do it quickly on you tube. I know next to 0 about swift or programming but I am starting to learn about it. I have research online and there is people that have the same issue but I haven't seen a solution other than contact apple. I believe that is something that has to do with background task but I get lost of course because I really don't understand the language yet.

this code comes up while the app is working

```
Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 4 (0x4), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

20 second after you switch apps or the screen goes dark this code appears and the app is killed

[ProcessSuspension] Background task expired while holding WebKit ProcessAssertion (isMainThread? 1).
```

Comment: This could be resolved in iOS 13.4? I'm also having the same trouble with iOS 13.3.1